# Using ASP.NET Membership provider (No login logic?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, authentication, asp.net-membership

I am new to using the asp.net membership provider, I have successfully linked my app to the aspnet membership database and have used the asp.net template that comes with the login screens etc.. What I dont understand is how is it logging in?, I do not see any logic behind the login file.

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    }
}
```

The above code is all that is there. Am i able to access such code anywhere?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look inside web.config file, you will see membership.

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" .../>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

By default, login control uses that Membership provider. For example, it calls ValidateUser method of Membership provider under the hood when you login. If you want to intercept the login logic -

1) write code in [LoggingIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggingin.aspx) event of Login control OR

2) create your own [custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

Custom membership provider is the way to go, if you want salted and hashed passwords.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is the login control. Look at your ASPX file and you'll see the control tag there. I don't believe you'll be able to see the source for the control, however.

Head over to MSDN to see all the ways you can customize the login control.

Answer (score 1):

Once the membership settings have you connected to the aspnetdb, the logging in is pretty much "for free".

The default login page you're referring to uses the ASP.NET [Login control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx), which performs the log in procedure through the default membership provider that you have set up in your web.config.

You can see I nice summary of how this works on MSDN here: [ASP.NET Login Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)